# Bind interface to implementation - target not instantiable when using the $defer property

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I've bound an interface to its implementation, like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Services\Mail\Contracts\Webhook;
use App\Services\Mail\Clients\MailgunWebhook;

class MailServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {

        $this->app->bind(
            Webhook::class,
            MailgunWebhook::class
        );
    }
}
```

I ran all of these:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
composer dumpautoload
```

Yet, I still got the *"Target is not instantiable error"*, when trying to use the binding.

**After I commented out the `$defer` property, the binding started to work.**

Why can't I use **[$defer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers#deferred-providers)** in this case?

Comment: Where is your implementation of the `provides` method?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the **[documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers#deferred-providers)**, to which I linked myself and failed to read it in full, `$defer` needs the `provides()` method.

In my case, all I needed to add in my service provider class is this:

```
public function provides() {

    return array(Webhook::class);
}
```

Thanks to James Fenwick for his comment.